# d3-drag 0.3.0 - "Cannot read property 'button' of null"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3-drag with a canvas a such:

```
select(canvas)
.call(
    drag()
    .container(canvas)
    .subject(partial(getNodeAtMouse, simulation, canvas))
    .on('start', someFunction))
```

However, I get the following error when I actually attempt to drag:

```
Cannot read property 'button' of null
```

from the following line in d3-drag (d3 original source code)

```
function defaultFilter() {
    return !d3Selection.event.button;
  }
```

If I remove that function (by specifying my own filter), I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null
```

In d3-selection (d3 original source code)

```
function sourceEvent() {
    var current = exports.event, source;
    while (source = current.sourceEvent) current = source;
    return current;
  }
```

This makes me think that there is some bug between the expectations of d3-drag and d3-selection. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, any one found working answer. I am also getting the same error, but no answer is working from the list

Comment: @Mallikarjuna ran into the same issue. I was originally using d3(latest version 5) but after downgraded it to d3v4 it now works!

Comment: @konekoya current I am using the D3 version 4.13.0

Comment: So, you mean it does work?

Comment: No, it is not working

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, for implementing zoom, move and drag you need to replace `import * as d3 from 'd3';` with the individual libraries:

```
import {event as d3Event} from 'd3-selection';
import {zoom as d3Zoom} from 'd3-zoom';
import {drag as d3Drag} from 'd3-drag';
import {select as d3Select} from 'd3-selection';
```

And then replace `d3.select()` with `d3Select()`, `d3.zoom()` with `d3Zoom()`, `d3.drag()` with `d3Drag()` and for example `d3.event.transform` with `d3Event.transform`.

Comment: I did this but am still having the same problem as the OP - I've also tried the stock `import * as d3 from 'd3';` as well as `Object.assign({}, d3, d3Zoom...)` as suggested in the docs

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this error when I was importing only `d3-zoom`. Solved it by importing both `d3-zoom` and `d3-selection`:

```
import {zoom} from 'd3-zoom';
import {select} from 'd3-selection';
```

Reference: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/27

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the same reason as this: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/185#issuecomment-419474845

I'm using Yarn and it had added two versions of d3-select. I manually removed one from yarn.lock and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you use yarn package manager - checkout yarn.lock. For all d3 packages only one version on d3-selection should be sticked. For example in my case I fixed it manually by linking all mentioned d3-selection packages to one node_module version like:

```
d3-selection@1, d3-selection@^1.0.1, d3-selection@^1.1.0, d3-selection@1.3.0, d3-selection@^1.4.0:
  version "1.4.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/d3-selection/-/d3-selection-1.4.0.tgz#ab9ac1e664cf967ebf1b479cc07e28ce9908c474"
  integrity sha512-EYVwBxQGEjLCKF2pJ4+yrErskDnz5v403qvAid96cNdCMr8rmCYfY5RGzWz24mdIbxmDf6/4EAH+K9xperD5jg==
```

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is from [this github issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/185#issuecomment-488386336). Add the following to your package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
        "d3-selection": "1.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but for me, the problem was because I wasn't importing the whole d3 package, which I'm guessing left the "event" undefined.

So instead of this:
`import {drag} from 'd3';`

Now I'm using:
`import * as d3 from 'd3';`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well when I **migrated yarn to npm** ...

You need to :

- Delete yarn.lock
- Delete package-lock.json
- Delete node_modules
- run `npm i`
- run `npm start`

and it's all good