# d3-drag - “Cannot read property 'button' of null”

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, nvd3.js

I am using the neo4j-d3 charts in my application as follows. I did checkout the git repo of Neo4j-d3 and created seperate repo as 'neo4jd3'

```
    import { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Neo4jd3 from 'neo4jd3';
import * as d3 from 'd3';


class xxx extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.getAllValues = this.getAllValues.bind(this);
        this.nodeRadius = 30
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getAllValues ();
    }

    createGraphObj(data) {
        let nodeRadius = this.nodeRadius
        let neo4jd3Obj = new Neo4jd3('#graphId', {
            nodeLetters: {
                'Test': (node) => {
                    return 'Check'
                },
                'Check': function (node) {
                    return 'Check'
                }
            },
            nodeColors: {
                'TestColor': 'rgba(250,204,163,1)',
                'CheckColor': 'rgba(124,212,248,1)',
            },
            nodeOutlineColors: {
                'TestColor': 'rgba(245,151,67,1)',
                'CheckColor': 'rgba(18,147,212,1)',
            },
            infoPanel: false,
            minCollision: nodeRadius,
            neo4jData: data,
            nodeRadius: nodeRadius,
            nodeletterSize: 16,
            onNodeClick: (node) => {

            }
        })
    }

    getAllValues () {
        this.xxx.getAllValues().then(res => {
            // console.log('----- getAllDomains -----', res)

            let temp = {
                "results": [{
                    "data": [{
                        "graph": res[0]
                    }]
                }]
            }
            this.createGraphObj(temp);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div id="graphId"></div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default xxx
```

. Grpah wise all are fine, but at the time of dragging I am getting the following error

```
Cannot read property 'button' of null
```

from the following code

```
function defaultFilter() {
    return !d3Selection.event.button;
}
```

I saw the following link

[d3-drag 0.3.0 - "Cannot read property 'button' of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885653/d3-drag-0-3-0-cannot-read-property-button-of-null#)

but no luck :(

Help me out for this one. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code here—there is not enough information in what you have written to know what is going on.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: are you importing the whole d3 library or just a subset of it?

Comment: Importing whole library like  - import * as d3 from 'd3'

Comment: I am also confused. Just installed the d3 using npm and trying to run. Loading is fine, but dragging is not. Inside of d3-zoom.js we have that defaultFilter()

Comment: Updated question with actual code

Comment: Issue is happend when we install the package with 'yarn', not with 'npm'. But why is so.,

Comment: I just posted a answer to the stackoverflow question that's linked to in the question, with details of what worked for me.

Comment: Take a look this answer. It helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706773/2467036