# d3 zoom is throwing cannot read property button of null error

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, datamaps

Following is the exact error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of null
    at SVGSVGElement.defaultFilter (zoom.js:12)
    at SVGSVGElement.wheeled (zoom.js:213)
    at SVGSVGElement.__onwheel.zoom (d3.js:1667)
```

Since I am using React.js with datamaps I am utilizing done function to handle the zoom event

These are my import statements,

```
import {zoom} from 'd3-zoom';
import {event as d3Event} from 'd3-selection';
```

following is the done function of datamap,

```
done: function(datamap) {
        datamap.svg.call(zoom().on("zoom", function() {
          console.log("Zoome event");
          datamap.svg.selectAll("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3Event.translate + ")scale(" + d3Event.scale + ")");
        }));
      },
```

I am using D3 version 4 and please find me a way to resolve this issue

Comment: What do you get if you log `d3Event.translate` and `d3Event.scale`?

Comment: Take a look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706773/2467036. It helped me to solve similar problem